# How to set an alias in powershell that has parameters?

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

I want to set an alias in powershell to compile my c++ file using the command

`g++ -std=c++17 -O2 any_file_name.cpp -o any_file_name -Wall`

I want to map this command to "co" so that when I type any `co any_file_name` it should compile. Is there a way of doing this ?

Comment: Write a function, some like: `function co { g++ -std=c++17 -O2 any_file_name.cpp -o any_file_name -Wall }`

Comment: I can write a function but I want it to work with any file name like it should work for a.cpp,,  b.cpp, x.cpp when I use that command.

Comment: Than, put that in a parameter: `function co ($any_file_name) { g++ -std=c++17 -O2 $any_file_name -o $any_file_name -Wall }`

Comment: I used function co ($any_file_name) { "g++ -std=c++17 -O2 $any_file_name -o $any_file_name -Wall" } and used set-Alias -Name drun -Value co. But when I used the command drun a.cpp the program is not compiling. Is it something to do with the extension .cpp

Comment: Remove the quotation marks inside of the function body.

Comment: I removed the quotation marks inside the function body now it's saying that I have to remove the extension .cpp from a.cpp to compile from the first $any_file_name inside the function body.